# SSIS: Move package to new server without having to change DB connection string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

Is there a way to set up an SSIS package to make the connection string dynamic in some way, or other setting, so that if you migrate to a new DB server you don't have to change all the SourceConnectionOLEDB settings to the new server name?

Comment: Just create a variable to store the connection string, so that you only have to update the variable once.

Comment: Create one configuration file and use it in every package or create an alias for your DB server.

Comment: do the deployment, either package deployment or project deployment

Comment: 2005/2008 or 2012+ with the package deployment model or 2012+ with the project deployment model?

Comment: Your ssis package is independent of the sql instance you execute it from.  The connection strings within the package don't change nor are affected so long as the datasource doesn't point to localhost or a trusted connection that now has to change do to user executing being different.  If you move your data sources that is when you need to worry about changing connection strings and the community is already starting to give you some dynamic ways of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options:

1) You can use the [Execute Package Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177184.aspx) to change your datasource, before running the package.
2) You can run your package using [DTEXEC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx), and change your connection by passing in a /CONNECTION parameter. Probably save it as a batch so next time you don't need to type the whole thing and just change the datasource as required.
3) You can use the SSIS XML [package configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167153(SQL.90).aspx) file. Here is a [walk through](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_2005_making_ssis_packages_portable.htm)
4) You can save your configrations in a database table.

Comment: 3 and 4 are useful anyway not big on 1 & 2 as answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

A easy way if the SSIS server is also the database server is to set up the connection using "." as the server name. Note that if you have a named instance, this will only work if you have the same instance name on both of the servers (".\InstanceName").